# Getting a TypeMismatch in Rails with Multiple Checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to create a multiple checkbox option on my form in Rails.

The main error I get is:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ContactsController#update
ContactGroup(#114780) expected, got "" which is an instance of String(#2400)
```

Contact.rb

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :contact_groups
    has_many :contact_types

end
```

ContactGroup.rb

```
class ContactGroup < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts

end
```

In the Form Partial:

```
  <div class="col">
    <%= form.label :contact_types, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes :contact_types, 
        ContactType.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that the form does display properly, by showing the various checkboxes.  However, it will not submit properly.

Here are my Contact Params in the Contacts Controller:

```
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :last_known_country, 
                                  :last_known_city, :mobile_phone_1, :mobile_phone_2, 
                                  :office_phone_1, :office_phone_2, :home_phone, 
                                  :other_phone, :email_1, :email_2, :email_3, 
                                  :email_4, :email_5, :website_1, :website_2, 
                                  :website_3, :website_4, :website_5, :website_6, 
                                  :website_7, :website_8, :contact_apps, :birthday, 
                                  :address_1, :address_2, :how_we_met, :things_I_like, 
                                  :best_memories, :areas_for_improvement, :notes, 
                                  contact_groups:[], contact_types:[])
end
```

Here is what it ends up submitting via the form:

```
   "contact_groups"=>["", "1", "2"],
   "contact_types"=>["", "1"],
```

Update Action:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to contact_url(@contact), notice: "Contact was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Prior to submitting the form, I am selecting both options for contact groups, and the only option available for contact types.  So I suppose that is the 1, 2 on the first row, and the 1 on bottom.  But why is it also submitting an empty string?  How to modify my code to make it save properly?

Update:

Here are the rails logs when I submit a new contact, and try to edit a contact:

```
    Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2023-04-09 18:37:42 -0400
    Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact"=>{"first_name"=>"Monroe", "last_name"=>"Mann", "last_known_country"=>"United States", "last_known_city"=>"Rye", "mobile_phone_1"=>"18084824136", "office_phone_1"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "email_1"=>"roe@monroemannlaw.com", "website_1"=>"", "contact_apps"=>"", "birthday"=>"", "address_1"=>"54 Cedar Pl\r\nApt 2", "how_we_met"=>"", "things_I_like"=>"", "best_memories"=>"", "areas_for_improvement"=>"", "notes"=>"", "contact_group_ids"=>["", "1"], "contact_type_ids"=>["", "1"], "office_phone_2"=>"", "other_phone"=>"", "email_2"=>"", "email_3"=>"", "email_4"=>"", "email_5"=>"", "website_2"=>"", "website_3"=>"", "website_4"=>"", "website_5"=>"", "website_6"=>"", "website_7"=>"", "website_8"=>"", "mobile_phone_2"=>"", "address_2"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
    Unpermitted parameters: :contact_group_ids, :contact_type_ids. Context: { controller: ContactsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007f83f16b01f8>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact"=>{"first_name"=>"Monroe", "last_name"=>"Mann", "last_known_country"=>"United States", "last_known_city"=>"Rye", "mobile_phone_1"=>"18084824136", "office_phone_1"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "email_1"=>"roe@monroemannlaw.com", "website_1"=>"", "contact_apps"=>"", "birthday"=>"", "address_1"=>"54 Cedar Pl\r\nApt 2", "how_we_met"=>"", "things_I_like"=>"", "best_memories"=>"", "areas_for_improvement"=>"", "notes"=>"", "contact_group_ids"=>["", "1"], "contact_type_ids"=>["", "1"], "office_phone_2"=>"", "other_phone"=>"", "email_2"=>"", "email_3"=>"", "email_4"=>"", "email_5"=>"", "website_2"=>"", "website_3"=>"", "website_4"=>"", "website_5"=>"", "website_6"=>"", "website_7"=>"", "website_8"=>"", "mobile_phone_2"=>"", "address_2"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact", "controller"=>"contacts", "action"=>"create"} }
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:25:in `create'
      TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:28:in `block in create'
      Contact Create (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("first_name", "last_name", "last_known_country", "last_known_city", "mobile_phone_1", "mobile_phone_2", "office_phone_1", "office_phone_2", "home_phone", "other_phone", "email_1", "email_2", "email_3", "email_4", "email_5", "website_1", "website_2", "website_3", "website_4", "website_5", "website_6", "website_7", "website_8", "contact_apps", "birthday", "address_1", "address_2", "how_we_met", "things_I_like", "best_memories", "areas_for_improvement", "notes", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "Monroe"], ["last_name", "Mann"], ["last_known_country", "United States"], ["last_known_city", "Rye"], ["mobile_phone_1", "18084824136"], ["mobile_phone_2", ""], ["office_phone_1", ""], ["office_phone_2", ""], ["home_phone", ""], ["other_phone", ""], ["email_1", "roe@monroemannlaw.com"], ["email_2", ""], ["email_3", ""], ["email_4", ""], ["email_5", ""], ["website_1", ""], ["website_2", ""], ["website_3", ""], ["website_4", ""], ["website_5", ""], ["website_6", ""], ["website_7", ""], ["website_8", ""], ["contact_apps", ""], ["birthday", ""], ["address_1", "54 Cedar Pl\r\nApt 2"], ["address_2", ""], ["how_we_met", ""], ["things_I_like", ""], ["best_memories", ""], ["areas_for_improvement", ""], ["notes", ""], ["created_at", "2023-04-09 22:37:42.257414"], ["updated_at", "2023-04-09 22:37:42.257414"], ["user_id", 1]]


  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:28:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (6.3ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:28:in `block in create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contacts/3
Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 9.0ms | Allocations: 4506)


Started GET "/contacts/3" for ::1 at 2023-04-09 18:37:42 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Contact Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:64:in `set_contact'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered contacts/_contact.html.erb (Duration: 7.7ms | Allocations: 844)
  Rendered contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 19.6ms | Allocations: 1835)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_topnav.html.erb:9
  Rendered layouts/_logged_in_nav.html.erb (Duration: 1.2ms | Allocations: 280)
  Rendered layouts/_topnav.html.erb (Duration: 4.4ms | Allocations: 1127)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 120.7ms | Allocations: 5889)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 121.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Allocations: 6860)


Started GET "/contacts/3/edit" for ::1 at 2023-04-09 18:37:52 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Contact Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:64:in `set_contact'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering contacts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  ContactGroup Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "contact_groups".* FROM "contact_groups"
  ↳ app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb:105
  Rendered contacts/_form.html.erb (Duration: 8.2ms | Allocations: 7047)
  Rendered contacts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 8.6ms | Allocations: 7109)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 9.2ms | Allocations: 7188)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms | Allocations: 8010)



ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column contact_groups.contact_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."contact_groups"."id" FROM "contact_groups" WHERE "contact_g...
                                                             ^
):
    102:
    103:           <div class="col">
    104:             <%= form.label :contact_groups, style: "display: block" %>
    105:             <%= form.collection_check_boxes :contact_group_ids, ContactGroup.all, :id, :name %>
    106:             </div>
    107:           </div>
    108:

app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb:105
app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb:3
app/views/contacts/edit.html.erb:8
```

Comment: Please add your contact model.

Comment: Can you show the entire params being submitted in the web server logs? Does Contact accept nested attributes for ContactGroup? Are we assuming that the form is for Contact since you don't explicitly state it or show the entire form?

Comment: @dbugger I just added contact.rb above

Comment: @Beartech I just added the error logs above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a type missmatch because you're assigning an array of ids to `contact_groups` which expects an array of model instances.

Use `contact_group_ids` and `contact_type_ids` instead:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :contact_type_ids, ContactType.all, :id, :name %>
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes*

---

If you want to have many-to-many relationship between `Contact` and `ContactGroup` you need to have a join table.

```rb
# db/migrate/*_create_contacts.rb

class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.references :user
    end
    create_table :contact_groups
    # join table
    create_table :contact_grouppings do |t|
      t.references :contact
      t.references :contact_group
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/user.rb                                                                                                                                                       
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
end

# app/models/contact_groupping.rb
class ContactGroupping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact_group
  belongs_to :contact
end

# app/models/contact_group.rb
class ContactGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contact_grouppings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_grouppings
end

# app/models/contact.rb
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :contact_grouppings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contact_groups, through: :contact_grouppings
end
```

Now when you submit `contact_group_ids` it should update `contact_grouppings` join table:

```
>> u = User.create
>> u.contacts.create!
>> 3.times { ContactGroup.create! }
>> u.contacts.first.contact_group_ids
=> []

>> u.contacts.first.contact_group_ids = [1]
  ContactGroup Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "contact_groups".* FROM "contact_groups" WHERE "contact_groups"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ContactGroupping Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "contact_grouppings" ("contact_id", "contact_group_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["contact_id", 1], ["contact_group_id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (6.9ms)  commit transaction
=> [1]
>> u.contacts.first.contact_group_ids = [2,3]
  ContactGroup Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "contact_groups".* FROM "contact_groups" WHERE "contact_groups"."id" IN (?, ?)  [["id", 2], ["id", 3]]
  TRANSACTION (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ContactGroupping Delete All (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "contact_grouppings" WHERE "contact_grouppings"."contact_id" = ? AND "contact_grouppings"."contact_group_id" = ?  [["contact_id", 1], ["contact_group_id", 1]]
  ContactGroupping Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "contact_grouppings" ("contact_id", "contact_group_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["contact_id", 1], ["contact_group_id", 2]]
  ContactGroupping Create (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "contact_grouppings" ("contact_id", "contact_group_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["contact_id", 1], ["contact_group_id", 3]]
  TRANSACTION (5.0ms)  commit transaction
=> [2, 3]

>> u.contacts.first.contact_groups
=> [#<ContactGroup:0x00007f212cd46530 id: 2>, #<ContactGroup:0x00007f212cd45ea0 id: 3>]
```

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association*

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex.

When I do the above, I get a new error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Contacts#edit
Showing /mnt/c/coding/contactpoints/app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb where line #105 raised:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column contact_groups.contact_id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."contact_groups"."id" FROM "contact_groups" WHERE "contact_g...

Comment: I also updated the original post with:
a) Contact.rb
b) My rails error logs

Comment: @MonroeMann see update. make sure you have join tables for many-to-many relationsips

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Just to be sure we are on same page: In my app, a user can create many Contact Groups, like School, Work, Summer Trip, etc.  A contact can be a member of many of these contact groups, and other contacts too can be added to the same contact groups.  Do I need a join table as you suggest in this situation?

Comment: @MonroeMann yes. Contact has many groups, and group has many contacts, that's many-to-many relationship, it needs a join table.

Comment: PS - If you have time, I have another issue on another project here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973371/rails-name-error-suddenly-appearing-out-of-nowhere  Maybe you are able to help deduce the issue here too?  Thanks @Alex

Comment: I am finally sitting down to try to create the join tables.  Once I get it working, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have it now working... in the command line.  When I add a contact group to a contact in the command line, and save it, it does show up in the browser on that contact's show page.  But for some reason, I can't do the same using the GUI on the edit page.  When I save the changes, the changes are not saved.  

Error I am receiving: 

Unpermitted parameter: :contact_group_ids. Context: { controller: ContactsController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00

Comment: Disregard!  I fixed it.  I found out that the error above was caused because I was listing contact_groups[] in the permitted paramaters instead of contact_group_ids.  It works now!

Comment: Thank you so much!  It really helped.  

To those reading this, here are some tips that may help:
1. Because each user can create and edit their own contact groups, I still had to keep 'has_many :contact_groups' in the user model.  So you may not be able to do precisely what Alex shares above.  
2. PragmaticStudio.com has a great Ruby on Rails course.  I also used their Many-to-Many lessons to help me better understand Alex's suggestions above.
3. Don't give up.  This many-to-many is complicated stuff.  Stick with it.  You'll get it, just like I did. :D