# Rails: Child record created before parent and throws RecordNotFound error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, nested-forms

I have a strange workflow whereby a child record is created first and then I want it associated with the parent through a nested form.  Here is an example using rspec:

Here are the models:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Child', dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'child_id', optional: true
end
```

My controller is standard:

```
def create
  @prent = Parent.new(parent_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @parent.save
      format.html { redirect_to @parent }
    else
      p @recipe.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end

def parent_params
  params.require(:parent).permit(
    :name,
    children_attributes: [
      :id, :_destroy
    ]
  )
end
```

Since the child already exists, I am only trying to associate it with the parent, not create an entirely new record.  Here is my test that fails with an error:

```
child = Child.create

expect {
  post "/parent", params: {
    parent: {
      name: "test",
      children_attributes: [{
        id: child.id
      }]
    }
  }.to change(Parent.all, :size).by(+1)
  .and change(Child.all, :size).by(0)
end
```

And the error I'm receiving is

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Child with ID=1 for Parent with ID=
```

Clearly it's because `Child` exists before `Parent` but I still feel this should be possible.  Is there a way to get this to work such that the existing child is associated with the parent when the parent is saved?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if the the child is already attached? I would either do it manually (not using nested attributes) or create a many-to-many association and manipulate entries in the join table using nested attributes.

Comment: @JanVítek I would expect to update it if the child is already attached

Comment: @JanVítek the trouble is that sometimes the child does not exist and needs to be created when the parent is submitted.  Feels like I'm trying to do too many things

Comment: By "update it if the child is already attached" you mean steal it from other parent? I don't think there is a universally correct behaviour for this and therefore the only way is some manual intervention. A part of the nested attributes behaviour may be salvaged but at least for the associating existing records, you'd have to reject them from the parent_params and associate them manually.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand.  No the child is actually a join table with other children and the parent would never be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to associate existing records when creating another, use `child_ids=` method.

> `collection_singular_ids=ids`
> Replace the collection with the objects identified by the primary keys in `ids`. This method loads the models and calls `collection=`.

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many*

```rb
# db/migrate/20230601025957_create_parents.rb
class CreateParents < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :parents
    create_table :children do |t|
      t.references :parent
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/parent.rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
end

# app/models/child.rb
class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, optional: true
end
```

```rb
# spec/requests/parent_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe "Parents", type: :request do
  it "POST /parents" do
    child = Child.create!
    expect do
      # don't forget to permit `child_ids: []`
      post "/parents", params: {parent: {child_ids: [child.id]}}
    end.to(
      change(Parent, :count).by(1).and(
        change(Child, :count).by(0)
      )
    )
  end
end
# 1 example, 0 failures
```

`children` is not a join table here, but if you have *through* associations set up, `*_ids` method will also just work. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75972917/207090

Comment: That did it!  I had a feeling this was possible.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` does not have the feature you're after, you can only create new children, or update the attributes of already associated children, you can't add existing children.

You *could* override the `children_attributes=` method so that it provided the functionality you were looking for if an `id` existed but was not already part of the `parent.children` (and then pass off to `super` for the normal behavior).