# multiple select fields for one attribute rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple select fields with the same attribute on each select field, though the attribute only detects the first select field which of course i don't want.

the view :

```html
<div class="dispo">
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
  <div class="di-in">
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
    -
    <%= form.select :disponibilities, [["6", "6"], ["7", "7"], ["8", "8"],  ["9", "9"],  ["10", "10"],  ["11", "11"],  ["12", "12"],  ["13", "13"],  ["14", "14"],  ["15", "15"],  ["16", "16"],  ["17", "17"],  ["18", "18"],  ["19", "19"],  ["20", "20"]] %> 
  </div>
</div>
```

my information_trainer.rb

```
class InformationTrainer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    has_many :disponibilitiess

end
```

I added the has_many association but still it renders me "6" in the console when I submit the form, I want it to memorise every selected number. Anyone has an idea how to fix this ?

Comment: to return an array of disponsibilities, it needs to be `form.select :disponibilities[],..etc`

Comment: Seems like the has_many is not actual relation here you are trying to add.
Either you can create one virtual model and store or You actually create one separate model/table and have that association.

With that using nested_attributes you can achieve this.

Or please describe the question in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `params` => `{"disponibilities"=>["1", "2", "3", "4"]}` then your select tag `name`s need `[]` at the end, which feels weird on a select tag:

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/" do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for "disponibilities" do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.select "", 1..10 %>
    <%= ff.select "", 1..10 %>
  <% end %>

  <%= select_tag "disponibilities[]", options_for_select(1..10) %>
  <%= select_tag "disponibilities[]", options_for_select(1..10) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
Parameters: {"disponibilities"=>["4", "3", "10", "9"], "commit"=>"Save "}
```

Maybe you want checkboxes or an actual multiple select box. If you're trying to change associations and the numbers are ids use `disponibility_ids`, but it won't work if there are duplicate selections, and you probably need to have a many-to-many relationship (like this *https://stackoverflow.com/a/75972917/207090*)

```rb
<%= f.collection_check_boxes "disponibility_ids", 1..10, :to_s, :to_s %>

<%= f.select "disponibility_ids", 1..10, {}, multiple: true %>
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html*

Comment: it worked fine, still it returns me on my view ["16", "18", "20", "20"], i'm more trying to have this [["16","18"],["20","20"]], so finally it can look like this : Mardi

Mercredi

Jeudi

Vendredi

Samedi

Dimanche

8h - 17h

8h - 17h

8h - 17h

8h - 17h

8h - 17h

8h - 12h